# Read-string does not always return a value

Tags: functions, minibuffer

I have written a small function to search MDN docs and display them on the browser.

However, sometimes the function does not work and an empty query is made.

My code is as follows:

```
(defun search-mdn (&optional querystring)                                       
  (interactive)                                                                 
  (if (not querystring)                                                         
      (search-mdn (read-string "What do you want to look up on MDN? "))         
      )                                                                         
  (let* ( (header "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=")              
         (footer "&topic=api&topic=css&topic=canvas&topic=html&topic=http&topic\
=js&topic=mobile&topic=apps&topic=svg&topic=webdev&topic=webext&topic=webgl")   
         (searchurl (concat header querystring footer)))                        
    (browse-url searchurl)                                                      
    )                                                                           
  )
```

Every time I call the function without parameters (search-mdn (read-string "What ...")) runs, however sometimes it does not call the search-mdn function with   a parameter, although I enter one.

Comment: You should just build the list of arguments in body of `interactive` rather than calling the same function, because it will return, and then the first call will continune (with `querystring` set to `nil`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @DoMiNeLa10 says is that you should have written:

```
(defun search-mdn (querystring)                                       
  (interactive
   (list (read-string "What do you want to look up on MDN? ")))
  (let* ((header "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=")
         (footer "&topic=api&topic=css&topic=canvas&topic=html&topic=http&topic\
=js&topic=mobile&topic=apps&topic=svg&topic=webdev&topic=webext&topic=webgl")
         (searchurl (concat header querystring footer)))
    (browse-url searchurl)))
```

Now the reason why this fixes your problem is not because using `interactive` magically fixes the problem: the root of your problem was simply that the `(let ...)` part of the code was written after the `if` rather than within the "else" part of the `if`, so when `querystring` is nil, your code first calls itself recursively with a valid string, and then continues execution "again" with the nil value.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how interactive worked. And I couldn't foresee that the execution would continue after making another function call. I see it now.